# "connected" and "linked" in one sentence

Tags: word-choice

> These events are inextricably connected with huge expenses and not necessarily linked with a sufficient revenue.

Is it okay? Maybe I should stick to one adjective.

> These events are inextricably connected with huge expenses and not necessarily with a sufficient revenue.

Comment: linked to, in any event.

Comment: high revenue, no a. It's just not a great sentence. The events give rise to enormous expense and do not generate sufficient revenue. That sounds like what you might mean.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to leave in "linked" just to make the meaning clear, the first sentence is better.

Answer (score 0):

Alternating synonyms is a common stylistic choice, and as long as it doesn't cause the sort of difficulty that FumbleFingers warns of in their comment, it is a positive. Make the slight difference between the words work for you, use different adverbs where appropriate, and it's generally good - especially where the degree of link (or whatever a word might refer to) is different, as in this case.

It avoids the potential lack of clarity of leaving it implicit in the second case, and avoids the unsightly repetition that using the same word would have.